# Android ScrollView onClickListener conflict

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, onclicklistener

I am creating a layout that has a scrollview, a button panel and some Textviews in it.
The text view and the button panel are included by using reusable views. The scrollView is coded onto the activity.

The problem is that the scrollview stops the OnClickListener from working. I know it is the scrollview as if I remove it the listener works. I have read about a conflict between scrollview and OnClickListener, and assume this is what is causing this. Does anyone know of any solutions to this problem.

I have not posted my code for this as there is a large body of code to post and I am looking for general comments on the problem, or anyone who has experience dealing with it, rather than a solution to my specific problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".BoResults" >

<include layout="@layout/buttonpanel"/>

<include layout="@layout/results"/>


    <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:paddingTop="400dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/include1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/include1">

         <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Pressure" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Solution Gas-Oil Ratio" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Oil Density" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Oil FVF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Oil Viscosity" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Oil Compressibility" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Free Gas SG" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Free Gas Z-factor" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Free Gas FVF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:text="Free Gas Compressibility" />

        </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
public void setup(){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout).findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout).findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout).findViewById(R.id.button3);      
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout).findViewById(R.id.button4);

            applyListener(layout,listener);

            Log.d("","run");

        }

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {    

            //conditions();

            switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent1=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;

            case R.id.button2:

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Black Oil")){
                Intent intent2=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, BoInputs.class);
                startActivity(intent2);}

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Dry Gas")){
                    Intent intent2=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, DgInput.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);}

                break;

            case R.id.button3:

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Black Oil")){
                Intent intent3=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, BoResults.class);
                startActivity(intent3);}

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Dry Gas")){
                Intent intent3=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, DgResults.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                }

                break;

            case R.id.button4:

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Black Oil")){
                Intent intent4=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, BoPlots.class);
                startActivity(intent4);}

                if(MainActivity.fuel.equals("Dry Gas")){
                Intent intent4=new Intent(ButtonHandler.this, DgPlots.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
                }


                break;

            }
        }
    };
protected static void applyListener(View child, OnClickListener listener) {
        if (child == null)
            return;

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
        }
        else if (child != null) {
            if(child.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                child.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }     
            if(child.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                child.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }
            if(child.getId() == R.id.button3) {
                child.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }
            if(child.getId() == R.id.button4) {
                child.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }     






        }
    }

    private static void applyListener(ViewGroup parent, OnClickListener listener) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
            } else {
                applyListener(child, listener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code plus the XML layout please!

Comment: @Akagami I had to edit the xml a bit to make it fit on stack, but the basics are there